# Is there access to Formik props inside <Field validate>

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have 2 fields. Second field should be auto populated once input of first field is validated OK. In order to populate second field i need to access formik's helper methods, which we normally have inside `<Field>`.

Portion of code related to formik:

```
const validateRoutingNumber = (value: string) => {
  // props.form.setFieldValue('financialInstitution', 'ANYTHING'); <---- Can do something like this?
  return;
}

<Formik initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={Schema} validateOnMount onSubmit={submitForm}>
   <Form>  
    <Field name="routingNumber" validate={validateRoutingNumber}>
      {(props: FieldProps) => (
        <TextField
          variant="outlined"
          {...props.field}
          {...textErrors(props.meta)}
          type="text"
          inputProps={{'aria-label': t('routingNumber')}}
        />
      )}
    </Field>
```

Is there a way to access to `props` inside `<Field>`, like we do inside `<TextField>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that i can access the desired formik properties. In similar manner how access is provided to formik properties on `<TextField>` level, access can be provided to `<Formik>` level using [render props tehnique](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

Portion of code to provide desired behavior:

```
const validateRoutingNumber = async (value: string, formikProps: FormikProps<any>) => {
  console.log('formikProps', formikProps);
  ....
}

<Formik initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={Schema} validateOnMount onSubmit={submitForm}>
  {(formikProps: FormikProps<any>) => (
    <Form>  
      <Field name="routingNumber" validate={(value: string) => validateRoutingNumber(value, formikProps)}>
        {(props: FieldProps) => (
        <TextField
```

There are nice video materials on youtube regarding formik usage - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TFIBPyitXo